# Can I replace the value in the properties file when I use the code pipeline?

Tags: aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-codecommit, cicd

I have a question about AWS CODEPIPELINE.

I implemented CICD using AWS CODEPIPLE.
I have a some proferties files, and I want to dynamically change the values of those files.

For example
if i have server.properties file and that have Server.Host = example.com , Server.Port = 7777 like below the image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3KbZ.png)

I want to change dynamically based on the server.
So I change value format like ${Server.host} and try replace it.

But I don't know how to change this value. Is it possible to change this value in code pipeline?

I tried using the parameter store, but it seems to be only available for setting environmental variables in yml files.

Thanks